# MongoDB query won't return object in my Express API (React)

Tags: mongodb, api

I have done this so many times before, but I can't seem to find the issue, it's probably something small and stupid. Take a look at the `/server.js` file here! (Shortened for demonstration purposes)

```
/* Make Mongoose promise based */
mongoose.Promise = Promise;  
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', options);
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error: '));

/* Routes */
app.route('/games')
    .post(postGame)
    .get(getGames);
app.route('/games/:id')
    .get(getGame)
    .delete(deleteGame);

app.route("*").get((req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('client/dist/index.html', { root: __dirname });
});

const port = 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Connected! Server listening on port: ${port}`);
});
```

Then for my **Game** model, I have that in `app/models/game.js`.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const gameSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required:true
        },
        year: {
            type: Number,
            required:true
        },
        description: {
            type: String,
            required:true
        },
        picture: {
            type: String,
            required:true
        },
        postDate : { type: Date, default: Date.now }
    }
);

export default mongoose.model('Game', gameSchema);
```

This is where I believe I am having the issue.

```
/* Import Game model schema */
import Game from '../models/game';

const getGames = (req, res) => {
    Game.find({}, (err, games) => {
    console.log(err, games)
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(games);
    });
}

const getGame = (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    Game.findById(id, (err, game) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(game);
    });
}

const postGame = (req, res) => {
  let game = Object.assign(new Game(), req.body);
  game.save(err => {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    }
    res.json({ message: 'Game successfully created!' });
  });
};

const deleteGame = (req, res) => {
  Game.remove(
    { _id: req.params.id },
    err => {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      }
      res.json({ message: 'Game successfully deleted!' });
    }
  );
};

export {
    getGames,
    getGame,
    postGame,
    deleteGame
};
```

> Just do be clear... I went into the `mongo` shell.

I did...

`connecting to: test`

`> db.createCollection('Game')`

`> db.Game.insert({name: "SSB", year: 2001, description: "Fun Game", picture: "http://google.com", postDate: "2017-01-03T08:51:45.888Z"});`

And when I type `> db.Game.find({});` I am returned with exactly what I have...

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("58c2223e32daa04353e35bdc"), 
    "name" : "SSB",
    "year" : 2001, 
    "description" : "Fun Game", 
    "picture" : "http://google.com", 
    "postDate" : "2017-01-03T08:51:45.888Z"
}
```

You see when I go to `http://localhost:8080/games` I am returned with an empty JSON and I just wanna know why. I am 70% sure, it is because it isn't connected to the right collection but I don't remember how to test that :(

Comment: Did you try to console log the response and see what happens?

Comment: @dsomel21 you did not provide any database name in the connection string. You can try to use `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/gamedb');` instead of `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', options);`

Comment: It logs out `[] null`. Anyways, @gypsyCoder your method didn't work. Do you think the issue could be that I didn't create a database? I just went to `mongo` shell and did createCollecction.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to make this a comment but it won't let me because I don't have a 50 reputation, but I believe I found the issue.

```
const getGame = (req, res) => {
const { id } = req.params;
Game.findById(id, (err, game) => {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err);
    }
    res.json(game);
  });
}
```

In this piece of code you are setting the id to req.params, but you need to set it to req.params.id which is what you passed in your route.

Should look like this:

```
const {id} = req.params.id;
```

If you logged id, you would probably get an object that says:

```
{ id: "[whatever_id_you_put_here]" }
```

however if you log req.params.id you should get the correct id you put in that spot..

The reason you're getting [] is because you're actually connected to the database and you are actually trying to "get" something, but that something doesn't exist so it sends an empty response.

I hope this helps..